# HP CP2025 Making it work on WIfi

Tags: networking

I have read all the threads and it's a bit confusing. Can my customer connect an Ethernet Cable from the  HP CP2025dn Printer to the back of one of his existing Google Mesh Pods, will this allow him to print wirelessly from anywhere in his house? Does he need to do anything additional to the Printer in order for it to print from the Laptop in another room? Thank you for being so helpful, Sincerely

Comment: Wireless printing primary only requires one thing, the printer and the client, connected to the same access point. If that’s not working you should edit your question with sufficient information to answer your question

Comment: I think I understand and it should work fine then, thank you